# ASP.Net web application VS ASP.net MVC web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new in Asp.Net framework. I get confuse in Asp.Net web application and Asp.Net MVC web application template as shown in the screenshot.

[image: Here you can see MVC and web application template screenshot]

I don't understand where to start.

I know that Asp.Net *web forms* now a days is not the big deal in developing web application because of new technology Asp.net MVC. If Web applications can be developed by using Asp.net Web application template then what is the need of Asp.net MVC and asp.net Web forms?
Is Asp.Net web forms , Asp.Net web Application and Asp.Net MVC are three different templates for developing web application then suggest me which are the best to go for in terms of getting job in future?
I currently using visual Studio 2015 professional.

Comment: Why not using Visual Studio 2017? See also [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/quickstart-aspnet-core?view=vs-2017) documentation link.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to asp.net start off with web forms. It’s a whole lot easier to navigate the code. Once you’re familiar with the framework mvc is a lot easier to understand.

EDIT:

Here is the simplest single page aspx page. It has no CS or designer file.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<html>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="ctlLabel1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="ctlTextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="ctlButton1" runat="server" OnClick="ctlButton1_Click" Text="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>


<script runat="server">


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
            ctlTextBox1.Text = "Hello 1";
        }
    }

    protected void ctlButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        ctlLabel1.Text = ctlTextBox1.Text;

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Are You means MVC is very similar to web forms?

Comment: All web site development tools end up with the same result - HTML rendered to a browser (assuming web pages here). This usually starts with a GET of HTML from the server and can be followed by a POST of data back to the server which a user has entered. The older Forms development is fine for smaller applications. ASP.NET MVC runs under IIS only, MVC Core runs under various technologies. MVC can do a lot of work for you and the tasks you need to do form into simple and repetitive patterns. Try writing the same small site using Forms and MVC

Comment: like pixelda said, start off with the most basic function and that is rendering HTML.

Comment: Thanks allot to give me guideline.  especially manit, pixelda and  manit.